# Python recursion not fully understood

Tags: python, recursion

EDIT: I have edited and clarified the code and the question.

EDIT EDIT: Before you can understand recursion, you must first understand recursion!

I can do this without recursion, but if you understand recursion, you should be able to do this with recursion. Which I cannot. So something is wrong with my understanding of recursion. How can I fix this code, i.e. what have I missed regarding recursion?

So, what I want to do is to do some trading. And each time some condition happens, I want to update some statistics and restart trading. I also keep track of how many times I have restarted trading, which is the task of variable "nr_restarts".

So when I am done, I have populated the variable "dfL" with the numbers [0,...,9] and I have restarted trading twice, so nr_restarts = 2. This is the output I want to bring to the user. However, I get this output only if I execute the line "sys.exit()". And in that case, the program terminates abruptly, so I can not bring the "dfL" list or nr_restarts to the user.

If I instead comment out "sys.exit()" line so that recursion continues until program execution finishes, then I can bring the dfL list and nr_restarts to the user. But in that case, the recursion rolls back, so nr_restarts goes from 0, 1, 2, and then back again. So nr restarts go to 0,1,2,1,0. So nr_restarts will be reported to the user as 0, which is not correct. And also the dfL list becomes weird, because recursion continues to add values beyond [0,...,9].

As I said, this can be done without recursion. But if you understand recursion, you should be able to to this with recursion. I cannot. Can you?

```
def Start_trading (dfL, start, end, nr_restarts):
    for idx in range (start, end):
        dfL.append (idx)
        if idx == 3: # some condition occurs, so restart trading
            dfL, nr_restarts = Start_trading (dfL, idx+1, end, nr_restarts+1)
        if idx == 7: # another condition occurs, so restart trading
            dfL, nr_restarts = Start_trading (dfL, idx+1, end, nr_restarts+1)
    print (dfL, nr_restarts)
    sys.exit()
    return dfL, nr_restarts

def Start ():
    start = 0
    end = 10
    nr_restarts = 0
    dfL = []
    dfL, nr_restarts = Start_trading (dfL, start, end, nr_restarts)
    return dfL, nr_restarts
```

Comment: `Restart_trade` creates a brand new `dfL`, throwing away the one that was passed in. 
 It then returns the new `dfL`, but in `Start_trading`, you don't save the result of `Restart_trade`.  You either need to modify the `dfL` list in place, or do `dfL = Restart_trade(...)`.

Comment: Thanx for your answer! However, I dont understand this apparently. I have added "dfL = Restart_trade (dfL, idx+1, end, nr_restarts+1)
and there is the same problem. Can you be more explicit how to fix my code?

Comment: The problem is, you haven't told us what this code is supposed to do.  I can't figure it out by examination.  And, by the way, `Restart_trade` does nothing; you could replace all those call with calls to `Start_trading`.

Comment: I have updated my question with some clarifying remarks. Basically, I want the recursion to stop after populating the dfL list to [0...9]. Instead, it continues to build the dfL list and makes it quite long, which is not what I want. 
Was this clearer?

Comment: Sorry, the description is still very unclear to me. What's the purpose of the code / of the output? The `dfL` list is filled in according to the expectations, because you firstly add 1 to 3 to it and then you do the recursion, adding 4 etc. into the same list, then you keep adding 4 etc. Regarding `sys.exit()`, this should simply terminate the program. Finally, to the very beginning of your question: if you print out `Start2 ...` at the end of your program, you can't expect that completely another line will be printed instead...?

Comment: Ok, I have refactored the code and the explanation. Is it clearer now?

Comment: Yes, I think it is much better now. :) The purpose and outputs are still a bit unclear, but I have tried to give you an answer anyway...

Answer (score 0):

According to the information given, I expect that:

- `nr_restarts` should be the *total* number of *recursive* calls of `Start_trading()`, so counting it like that - it equals 3, not 2
- if the program doesn't throw an error, `dfL` returned will be always a constant list [0..9] => removing it from the recursion & logging some other potentially useful data instead
- the "business" logic of the calls is already correct (i. e. passing just `start` and `end` to them is enough, because these are the only variables that affect the flow in some way in the OP)

So here comes a simplified code that *probably* satisfies the requirements:

```py
def Start_trading(start, end):
    print('Start_trading', start, end)
    nr_restarts = 0
    for idx in range (start, end):
        if idx in (3, 7): # some condition occurs, so restart trading
            nr_restarts += 1 + Start_trading(idx + 1, end)
    return nr_restarts

start = 0
end = 10
nr_restarts = Start_trading(start, end)
print(list(range(start, end)), nr_restarts)
```

This outputs:

```
Start_trading 0 10
Start_trading 4 10
Start_trading 8 10
Start_trading 8 10
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] 3
```

Comment: Almost there! I have updated my code. I want to return both dfL and nr_restarts to the user. And I do things with dfL  in my code, so I cannot make it static. But thanx for your help. Unfortunately, this is not the answer I am looking for, so I cannot give you credit. :(
The purpose is a bit complicated. It is a High Frequency Trading strategy and it would be too much to write how it works.

Comment: OK, so wouldn't it suffice if the `dfL` list is put back where it was, while returning [0..9] to the user? Otherwise I think that changing your post to a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is the only way to go... ;)